# Angular2: how to access a formControl value on a nested formBuilder form

Tags: angular, formbuilder

How can I get the value of `this.resFormGroup.patientName.lastname.value` without using `[ngModel]`?

What are the purpose of `name="resForm"`, `[formGroup]="resFormGroup"` and `#resNgForm="ngForm"` in the HTML `<form>` tag?

Do I need the template reference variable `#resNgForm` since I have the `[formGroup]="resFormGroup"`?

This is my component:

```
// FormBuilder
this.resFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  patientName: this.formBuilder.group({
    firstname: ['', Validators.required],
    lastname: ['', Validators.required]
  }),
  address: this.formBuilder.group({
    street: [],
    zip: [],
    city: []
  })
});
```

This is my template:

```
<form name="resForm" [formGroup]="resFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #resNgForm="ngForm">
  <fieldset formGroupName="patientName">
      <legend>Name</legend>
  <label>Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" [(ngModel)]="myFirstName">

  <label>Lastname:</label>
  <input type="text" ***formControlName="lastname"***>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset formGroupName="address">
      <legend>Address</legend>
      <label>Street:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="street">

      <label>Zip:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="zip">

      <label>City:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="city">
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!resNgForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

My submit button:

```
 onSubmit() { 
   console.log("Submit button pressed [ngModel: " + this.myFirstName + "]    [Form: " + this.resFormGroup.controls["patientName"].dirty + "]"); 
 }
```

With `[ngModel]`, I can get the first name; I can also access the `dirty` attribute of the `formGroup`'s `patientName`.

Comment: I was thinking and tried this with no luck. console.log("Nested form value: [" + this.resFormGroup.controls["patientName"].controls["lastname"].value + "]");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this tutorial about [dynamic form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html), they used a very simple way to show the values of the whole form without [ngModel].

How to get the formBuilder form values? The answer is 'this.myForm.value'.

### Example code

For example:

```
onSubmit(model: ResCrud) {  
    console.log("Nested Control: " + JSON.stringify(this.resFormGroup.value));
}
```

### How it looks in the web console

[image: angular formbuilder nested value example]

Comment: very surprised that this isn't included in the documentation for angular; it was really hard to see how to access values of nested groups and controls.